# Quantifying voice deepness of singing voices using python

Tags: python, voice

I want to quantify the deepness of a voice in a float representation using python. For example, deep voice may be represented by score lower than 0, and a high voice (the opposite of deep) by a score higher than 0. An example of a deep voice can be compared with Arnold Schwarzenegger's voice and a high voice with the voice of a young kid.

I have not found any clear approaches from googling to solve this problem. I have tried using a [timbral model](https://github.com/AudioCommons/timbral_models) to get the timbre score, but it seems that the calculations are not useful. That is, there is no huge difference between the scores of deep voices and high voices.

Based on this [source](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-tool-that-measures-how-deep-a-persons-voice-is), I can use the FFT analysis. However, I do not understand how to reduce the FFT graph into a single representation of the deepness of the voice.

So how do I progress after obtaining analysis using FFT? In a broader question, how do I represent the deepness of a voice as a float representation specifically using Python?

Edit: For extra information, the data set that I want to quantify consists of singing voices. I have obtained the FFT output and reduced the time frame dimension by the mean operation, so I am left with the mean result against the frequency bin.

Because of the data set having a significant pitch feature, the peaks of vector for both deep and high voice are similar when both voices are singing the same note. My inference is that this is due to the same harmonic generated by both voices. (Feel free to correct my interpretation.)

What are the effective ways to differentiate deep voice and high voice that are singing the same note?

Answer (score 1):

You can get statistics on the sample, in time space as well as frequency space. Usually you'd calculate mean, median, variance and entropy from both representations. There are other values you could get but these are just the basics. This way you get a vector of values from a sample of the signal.

For better results you could do these calculations on overlapping windows of the signal in both representations and this way you get a larger and more information dense vector of characteristics.

In this particular problem, I would calculate the energy and the integral of the Fourier transform of the signal in different frequency bands, since you would expect larger values in the lower frequencies on a deep voice.

The algorithm should look something like

1. Apply FFT to signal
2. Split result in bands
3. Calculate energy on each band, append result to an array
4. Sum values on each band, append result to the array
5. Do any other calculations you consider appropriate

The result will be a vector of values that summarize the signal.

Comment: im using librosa for loading audio files; for clarification, is `overlapping windows` the same as frames in librosa

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the same.

Comment: I have tried this, and my approach did not solve my problem. I have just updated the question with the result from my approach. Do you have suggestions that can be used specifically for my problem? Or is there any improvements for my current approach?